# contract creation initialization returns data with length of more than 24576 bytes,

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

How do I fix this issue? It turns out this limit was introduced with EIP-170 and restricts the deployment of contracts with large initialization bytecode.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this here are a few options to  try out:
Review and optimize your contract code: Look for any unnecessary or duplicated code, large data structures, or inefficient algorithms that could be simplified or optimized. By refactoring your code, you may be able to reduce the overall bytecode size.

Split your contract into multiple contracts: If your contract is large and complex, consider breaking it down into smaller, modular contracts. This can help reduce the bytecode size of each individual contract and make the deployment process more manageable.

Use contract libraries: If there are common functionalities or code segments that are reused across multiple contracts, consider extracting them into separate libraries. By using libraries, you can avoid duplicating code in each contract and reduce the bytecode size.

Remove unnecessary dependencies: Check if all the imported contracts and libraries are actually required for your contract's functionality. If any dependencies are not needed, remove them from your contract to reduce the bytecode size.

You can also take away imports if your solidity file is inheriting from already existing imports.
Example:
```pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import './StringUtils.sol';
import "./Merger.sol";

contract MergerCompany is Merger {
// ...
}```

And you can also reduce the code to a smaller number before deployment.

````
    ```function registerCompanies(address _companyaddress, string memory _companyname, string memory _companyboxaddress, string memory _companyscope, uint256 _companydateestablished, uint256 _yearsactive) public returns (address, string memory, string memory, string memory, uint256, uint256) {
require(_yearsactive >= 5, "You are not within the year range");
require(companies[_companyaddress] != true, "You are already registered");

newcompany = Company(_companyaddress, _companyname, _companyboxaddress, _companyscope, _companydateestablished, _yearsactive);
companystore[_companyaddress].companyaddress = _companyaddress;
companystore[_companyaddress].companyname = _companyname;
companystore[_companyaddress].companyboxaddress = _companyboxaddress;
companystore[_companyaddress].companyscope = _companyscope;
companystore[_companyaddress].companydateestablished = _companydateestablished;
companystore[_companyaddress].yearsactive = _yearsactive;

emit registerCompaniesEvent(_companyaddress, _companyname, _companyboxaddress, _companyscope, _companydateestablished, _yearsactive);
companyregistered.push(newcompany);

return (_companyaddress, _companyname, _companyboxaddress, _companyscope, _companydateestablished, _yearsactive);
````

}```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).